# Wordpress - Posts con etiqueta noindex como quitar la?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, seo, wordpress-imagenes

Tengo un blog con wordpress, que añadi el sitemap al google search console hace más de 1 mes , en el google search console en el apartado  **errores de rastreo v**eo muchos de este tipo

**Cobertura : La URL enviada contiene la etiqueta "noindex"**

Último : rastreo 6 mar. 2020 18:04:30

Rastreador:  Robot de Google para smartphones

¿Se permite el rastreo? : Sí

¿Se permite la indexación? No: se ha detectado la etiqueta·"noindex" en la metaetiqueta "robots"

Yo he mirado en la edición de la entrada y no veo ninguna etiqueta de  "noindex" , luego he mirado el codigo fuente de la web (link en questión) y no veo nada en el "head" que indique "noindex"

Adjunto una captura de como tengo configurada la entrada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto en Wordpress no permite editar ese tipo de etiquetas desde el formulario de Entradas, esta es seguramente definida por el Tema que tengas instalado el cual es quien tiene el poder de saber que etiquetes van en la plantilla que usa para renderizar las entradas.

En este caso es necesario saber que tema estas usando y ver si existe en su configuración algún parámetro para editar la etiqueta Robots del html.

Esta etiqueta luce algo asi `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` y puede no estar en el head, puede probar con extenciones que ayudan a ver esa etiquetas mas facilmente como [META SEO inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meta-seo-inspector/ibkclpciafdglkjkcibmohobjkcfkaef)

Answer (score 2):

Existe una configuración general de Wordpress, donde puedes indicar si quieres que el sitio sea indexado por buscadores o no. Esto se configura en la instalación y luego se puede modificar desde el administrador de Wordpress:

- Vas a Ajustes > Lectura
- Buscas la opción: Visibilidad en los motores
  de búsqueda, y desmarcas "Disuade a los motores de búsqueda de
  indexar este sitio"

Si esta opción ya estaba desmarcada, entonces seguramente tengas algún plugin de SEO instalado, que te permita controlar qué entradas muestras y cuáles no. De ser así, por favor indicanos qué plugins tenés para que te pueda seguir ayudando.

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenos días!
A mi me pasa lo mismo. Acabo de poner en marcha mi página web que se llama [www.alimentaciónmilagrosa.org](http://www.xn--alimentacinmilagrosa-k8b.org) y la entrada https://www.alimentacionmilagrosa.org/alimentacion-perjudicial/ Google dice que no me la indexa porque tienen una etiqueta meta robots noindex. Tengo instado el Yoast Seo y en esta entrada he puesto que se indexe y, además, tengo la opción de "Disuadir a los motores de búsqueda de indexar este sitio" desmarcada.

Cuando veo el código Html de la entrada, veo que tengo la etiqueta de noindex en el Head y la quiero poner en index pero, al hacer el cambio, no se guarda.

Quisiera que me ayudase, por favor, a saber dónde puedo cambiar esta etiqueta de noindex, pues ya me han dicho que lo haga en el fichero real y no sé dónde encontrarlo

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta..

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/318277)